# f:ajax will not render anything inside of an h:inputFile tag

Tags: ajax, jsf-2.2, mojarra, wildfly-10

I have been plagued with an issue for the past few days that I cannot solve. I am using `Mojarra 2.2.12` on `Wildfly 10`.

My problem is that when I use an `f:ajax` tag inside of an `h:inputFile` tag and attempt to re-render any component, using either the component's ID, `@form`, `@all`, or anything else, *nothing is re-rendered. Ever.* However, it works absolutely fine within an `h:commandButton` or other components.

Here is a simple example.

I have an `xhtml` file called `index.xhtml`. This file contains an `h:message`, `h:inputFile`, and `h:commandButton`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="test" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:message for="test" />
        <br />
        <h:inputFile value="#{uploadController.uploadedFile}">
            <f:ajax render=":test" />
        </h:inputFile>
        <h:commandButton value="Push me!"
            action="#{uploadController.buttonPushed}">
            <f:ajax render=":test" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I also have a `ManagedBean` class called `UploadController`, which logs messages upon an action taking place, and is supposed to display a message inside of the `h:message` tag once the form is re-rendered.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UploadController {

    private Part uploadedFile;

    public Part getUploadedFile() {
        return uploadedFile;
    }

    public void setUploadedFile(Part uploadedFile) {
        this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
        System.out.println("File Uploaded!");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("test", new FacesMessage("File Uploaded!"));
    }

    public void buttonPushed()
    {
        System.out.println("Button pushed!");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("test", new FacesMessage("Button Pushed!"));
    }
}
```

The expected result is that when you select a file, it will "upload" the file and then display "File Uploaded!" in the `h:message` once the ajax re-renders the page. Then if you push the button, it will display "Button Pushed!" in that same `h:message`.

The actual result is that, yes, "File Uploaded." is printed to the console, but the page never re-renders and the message never appears. The button, on the other hand, works perfectly, and the message appears just like it should.

I have absolutely no idea what to do from here. I'm a beginner to JSF. Why does the ajax not re-render inside the `h:inputFile`, but it works perfectly fine in the `h:commandButton`? Is this a bug? How can I achieve the desired results without refreshing the page?

Comment: What is the `encType` you defined in the `h:form`

Comment: @SubodhJoshi http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp it's required for file uploads (I get an error if I don't have it)